# ACTION_VIEW and getAbsolutePath

Tags: java, android

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Подтверждение") //title
    .setItems(R.array.your_choice, new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch(which){
                case 0:
                    Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("file://" + directory.getAbsolutePath()));
                    startActivity(i);`
```

Why I cant open file? I am try, but phone shows error. Another phone shows two programms for opening: Acrobat and torrent, but how i can open jpg and mp3 files with torrent? What is wrong? How android creates list of programms for opening?